# Geolocation - Not requesting for users' location on a mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I'm using the jQuery Plugin [jQuery gelocation](https://github.com/manuelbieh/jQuery-Geolocation) to find a phone number nearest you. Seems to work fine when running on my desktop PC. I get the prompt to share my location. But when I try to do this on a device - Both iOS and Android, using various different browsers too. I don't get the prompt.

Am I doing something wrong? Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1bg8x0ro/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $.geolocation.get(
            {
                success: showMyPosition,
                error: noLocation
            }
    );

    function showMyPosition(position)
    {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;

        $.ajax(
                {
                    type        : 'GET',
                    url         : 'branch_search.php',
                    data        : {lat: lat, long: long},
                    dataType  : 'json',
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        $('.tel').html(data);
                    }
                }
        )
    }

    function noLocation(error)
    {
        // No Location Supplied Or Error (Show Base)...
    }

});
```

When I run the demo on my device(s) I do get prompted for a location, So I suspect something is missing somewhere.

Thanks

Comment: May be [__Geolocation API removed from unsecured origins in Chrome 50__](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only?hl=en)

Comment: Great, makes sense. Needs to be over https for it to work in Chrome. Mobile device is running Google Chrome.

Comment: On Desktop web as well if you are in _Chrome > 50_